# Any tools to identify undefined CSS/HTML classes?

Tags: html, css

Are there any tools out there that can look at my website HTML and tell me that (for example) "there is an HTML element at mysite.com/example.html using a class of SOMECLASS but SOMECLASS is not defined in any included CSS files".

?

Comment: Keep in mind that classes might well be used for other purposes than styling - eg. adding behavior to elements using Javascript. The tool you are looking for might still exists, though.

Comment: Yes, I do realise this. I think the class attribute is *mostly* being used solely for CSS however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try out a Firefox plugin like [Dust-me-selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/)

Comment: Looks to be just what I was afer! Thanks.

Comment: @Dougal it's worth baring in mind that DustME will only check the current status of a page, so `@media` based rules or rules which only apply to AJAX content etc. will be marked as unused. Just incase you get too keen deleting redundant rules from the CSS!

Comment: To me this seem to find defined selectors in your css files and point out the ones that are not used. But this question is about the opposite: css used in your HTML files that are not defined in any of your css files.

Comment: Hm, I might be doing something wrong but as far as I could tell DustMe only lists selectors in stylesheets that do not match anything in the current HTML, not classes used in HTML that are not matched by any selector in any stylesheet...

Comment: I can't make it work. It looks like DustME  doesn't work anymore ((

Comment: Alas, this tool seems to no longer exist.

Answer (score 13):

I've created a snippet that does exactly that: https://gist.github.com/kdzwinel/426a0f76f113643fa285

You can run it in the DevTools console and the sample output will look like this:

[image: Sample output from the CSS un]

Answer (score 0):

You could try inspecting with [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com)

Comment: OK... so what do you do _exactly_ in Firebug, to identify undefined CSS classes? Especially if you have hundreds of those in a page?

Comment: I can't see how Firebug does something with undefined CSS classes. ((

Answer (score 0):

There is a free Windows desktop tool that can scan a local web project folder and output undefined css classes, i.e. classes that are used in html but are not defined in any css. It also takes JavaScript into account to some degree.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cssscanner/

[image]

All other answers either didn't work for me or didnt understand the question (including the accepted answer). This one I just tested myself and it works surprisingly well, though it won't catch *every* edge case.